# how do you hide a li when click on the hyerplink inside it using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I'm trying to hide a li list item when the link inside is clicked i.s

```
<ul>
<li id="list_1" class="list"><a href="http://">hide</a>
</li>

<li id="list_2" class="list"><a href="http://">hide</a></li>

<li id="list_3" class="list"><a href="http://">hide</a></li>

<li id="list_4" class="list"><a href="http://">hide</a></li>
</ul>

<span class="updateNumber">0</span>​
```

and everytime a li item is hidden, increase the number of updateNumber text by 1. thanks

Comment: sorry for the newbie question, I'm quite new to all this javascript stuff thanks!! :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$('li a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

The selector `li a` finds all `<a>` tags inside any `<li>` (I've kept it simple here so it'll be greedy). We then use [`$.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind an event handler to the `click` event.

Now we use an anonymous function (a function without a name) to do our stuff in. Here, we pass `e` into the function as an argument. `e` contains the event object so we can do `e.preventDefault()` on the next line. This line stops the browser doing it's default behaviour on the link, which is to navigate to the URL in the `href` attribute in the `<a>` tag.

The line `$(this).parent().hide()` is the important one. Here, `$(this)` references the link that was clicked, so doing [`$(this).parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) we can access the parent node (tag) of the `<a>` which is an `<li>` in this case. Adding [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) to the end of it hides the `<li>` and you're done.

---

To update your `.updateNumber` span, add this code to your click handler function:

```
var currentNumber = parseInt($('.updateNumber').text());

currentNumber++;

$('.updateNumber').text(currentNumber);
```

The first line gets an integer from the text within your span and assigns it to a variable called `currentNumber`. [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) will attempt to turn whatever is inside the span into an integer.

The second line `currentNumber++;` takes the current value we got from the span and increments it by one (the `++`) bit.

We then want to replace the text displayed in the span with the new, updated value, so we put the new value back into the span by using [`$.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) again:

```
$('.updateNumber').text(currentNumber);
```

Note that using `$.text()` without passing it a string to use will *retrieve* the element's text, whereas supplying `$.text()` with an argument such as `"Hello world, I'm a string"` will put that string into the target element.

---

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/r522Y/) is a working demo proudly produced and sponsored by @Reigel from the comments.

Comment: @Reigel Woo! Thanks for that. I've edited it into my answer :-)